# Create flow type that enforces React.Element has certain prop

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to use the `React.Element` type from the React library with Flow like this:

```
import type { Element } from "react";

interface Keyed {
    componentKey: string,
}

type KeyedElement<E: Keyed> = Element<E>;

const keyedGood: KeyedElement<*> = <div componentKey="keyed" />; // no flow error
const keyedBad: KeyedElement<*> = <div />; // flow error, componentKey is required
```

The intention is that KeyedElement will be a type for react elements that must have a required `componentKey` prop. As I've defined the KeyedElement type, it does not surprise me that this doesn't work, as I haven't indicated that the `componentKey` property needs to be on the elements `props` in any way, but hopefully it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

Anyone have any idea how I can make this work?